# Kotlin Suspending versions of InputStream and OutputStream

Tags: kotlin

Astoundingly, Kotlin doesn't seem to provide suspending versions of `InputStream` and `OutputStream`.

It's not hard to roll your own, but that doesn't give you the kind of default compatibility with other code that these ubiquitous interfaces provide in Java.

What would I use for suspending stream interfaces in Kotlin if I wanted to maximize interoperability without adapters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the primary way for doing IO with purely Java APIs is just calling blocking methods in the context of `Dispatchers.IO`.

However, there is [ktor-io](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor) library by JetBrains that implements IO in a purely suspending way.